# Python imports: Will changing a variable in "child" change variable in "parent"/other children?

Tags: python, import

Suppose you have 3 modules, a.py, b.py, and c.py:

a.py:

```
v1 = 1
v2 = 2
etc.
```

b.py:

```
from a import *
```

c.py:

```
from a import *
v1 = 0
```

Will c.py change v1 in a.py and b.py? If not, is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All that a statement like:

```
v1 = 0
```

can do is bind the name `v1` to the object `0`.  It can't affect a different module.

If I'm using unfamiliar terms there, and I guess I probably am, I strongly recommend you read Fredrik Lundh's excellent article [Python Objects: Reset your brain](http://effbot.org/zone/python-objects.htm).

Answer (score 2):

The `from ... import *` form is basically intended for handy interactive use at the interpreter prompt: you'd be well advised to never use it in other situations, as it will give you nothing but problems.

In fact, the in-house style guide at my employer goes further, recommending to always import a module, never contents from within a module (a module from within a package is OK and in fact recommended). As a result, in our codebase, references to imported things are always qualified names (`themod.thething`) and never barenames (which always refer to builtin, globals of this same module, or locals); this makes the code much clearer and more readable and avoids all kinds of subtle anomalies.

Of course, if a module's name is too long, an `as` clause in the import, to give it a shorter and handier alias for the purposes of the importing module, is fine. But, with your one-letter module names, that won't be needed;-).

So, if you follow the guideline and always import the module (and not things from inside it), `c.v1` will always be referring to the same thing as `a.v1` and `b.v1`, both for getting AND setting: here's one potential subtle anomaly avoided right off the bat!-)

Remember the very last bit of the Zen of Python (do `import this` at the interpreter prompt to see it all):

```
Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!
```

Importing the whole module (not bits and pieces from within it) preserves its integrity as a namespace, as does always referring to things inside the imported module by qualified (dotted) names. It's one honking great idea: do more of that!-)

Comment: So you never "from datetime import datetime"; you always import datetime, and type "datetime.datetime" every time?  That's a terrible style guide.

Comment: @Glenn, to your question, "yes"; to your opinion, I don't know of any Python style guide actively accepted (and enforced, via  "readability reviews") by more Python committers (including Guido;-), AND our Python SW seems to be reasonably successful (including time to market, maintainability, performance [cfr YouTube, Python-based AND fast], etc), so I wonder on what empirical data you base that opinion. Yep, PEP 8 does accept "importing a class", but Guido wrote that _before_ he joined Google and met (and accepted, and enforced) our awesome style guide!-)

Comment: Writing "datetime.datetime" is terribly ugly; "datetime.datetime.now" is even uglier; coding styles that encourage ugly code are bad.  More broadly, having the module as a namespace is simply unhelpful when the class itself is a namespace.  Import the level which is intended as a namespace--for many modules, that's the module itself, but for classes like datetime, it's the class.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you just need to access it correctly (and don't use import *, it's evil)

c.py:

```
import a
print a.v1 # prints 1
a.v1 = 0
print a.v1 # prints 0
```