# how to modify imported variables in python

Tags: python, django

In `a.py` ,I imported django's `settings.py`,I Need to Modify `settings.DEBUG` .

but how to do it in python script?

I did this but nothing changed  , **`settings.DEBUG=False`**

Comment: This thread explains your predicament:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251611/python-imports-will-changing-a-variable-in-child-change-variable-in-parent

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/#altering-settings-at-runtime   I think this is you want.

Just like it saied:

```
from django.conf import settings

settings.DEBUG = True   # Don't do this!
```

`The only place you should assign to settings is in a settings file.`

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to do a bit of research about different ways of doing 'local' settings for django.

There are lots of different ways. The way I do it is described in detail at [Modular Django Settings](http://schinckel.net/2012/02/01/modular-django-settings/).